# Jquery AjaxSubmit + json datatype stripped HTML in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-9

I'm doing a file upload using jquery form.js. The server side code returns a json formatted string, with one of the fields being "content". The content field has an HTML form, that I just grab and spit out on the page in a div.

This works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox, but fails in IE9. IE9 strips all opening HTML tags. I've been googling all day long and tried a whole lot of things, but I can't fix it.

Here is my Jquery code:

```
    $('#file_form').on("change", ".file_upload_field", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var options = {
            url: '/ajax/process',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
              $('#upload-confirm').show().html(response.data.content);
            }
        };

        $('#my-form').ajaxSubmit(options);
    });
```

Response is structed like this

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "success",
  "data": {
    "content": "<form><input type=\"text\" /></form>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response is not valid json, a valid version would be

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "success",
    "data": {
        "content": "<form><input type=\"text\" /></form>"
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah Sorry ... I should have put the backslashes in there. They are in there. I'll update the question