# IE9 stripping opening HTML tags in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, internet-explorer-9

PHP is returning the following JSON object:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "message": "PLM File read.",
  "value": "<h2>Select Columns</h2>"
}
```

Which is handled nicely in Chrome, Firefox, etc.

I need to support IE9, and IE9 is stripping out the opening `<h2>` tags from `value` (pardon the screenshot, I am running IE9 in a VM)

[image: IE9 watch tab - opening html tags stripped]

JSONLint says my JSON object is valid.

I've tried padding the string with "sacrificial" tags (additional `<h2>`) but those are also stripped out.

In a larger returned string (a `<div>` containing other tags) *all* opening HTML tags are stripped out - so it sounds like IE9 just hates opening HTML tags!

IE9 is running in "IE9 standards mode".

(Similar to this question - [Jquery AjaxSubmit + json datatype stripped HTML in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650062/jquery-ajaxsubmit-json-datatype-stripped-html-in-ie9) - which is unanswered)

Comment: Have you tried escaping the < and > characters?

"\<h2\>Select Columns\<\/h2\>"

Comment: I just did - that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

By using `htmlentities()` on the string prior to echoing with `json_encode()`, the tags were preserved!